# Why isn't my xfuncname working in my .gitconfig file?

Tags: git

I'm trying to setup a hunk header for `.natvis` files.  For some reason, it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm following their instructions from [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header), which doesn't say much in terms of restrictions of the regex, such as, is the matched item considered the hunk header or do I need a group? I have tried both with no success.  This is what I have:

```
[diff "natvis"]
    xfuncname = "^[\\\t ]*<Type[\\\t ]+Name=\"([^\"])\".*$"
```

I've also added to my `.gitattributes` file (even though I'm not positive that it is necessary):

```
*.natvis diff=natvis
```

I've tried `\t` instead of `\\\t` as well as replacing the entire regex with just `<Type.*` with no luck. I'm using `git version 2.7.0.windows.1` on `Windows 8.1`. **EDIT:** I upgraded to `git version 2.11.1.windows.1` on `Windows 8.1` and even tried `git version 2.8.3` on `cygwin64` on `Windows 8.1` with the same results.

As a test file, I have the following `test.natvis` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">

  <Type Name="test">
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="var">var</Item>













      <!-- Non-blank line -->
      <Item Name="added var">added_var</Item>


      <Item Name="var2">var2</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

with the `<Item Name="added var">added_var</Item>` being the new line added.

I'm really not sure why this is so difficult.

### EDIT:

Here is a sample output of what I am getting:

```
$ git diff --word-diff
diff --git a/test.natvis b/test.natvis
index 73c06bc..bc0f549 100644
--- a/test.natvis
+++ b/test.natvis
@@ -18,6 +18,7 @@


      <!-- Non-blank line -->
      {+<Item Name="added var">added_var</Item>+}


      <Item Name="var2">var2</Item>
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in test.natvis.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Even using `xfuncname = "^.*$"` I would have expected that `<!-- Non-blank line -->` would have shown up as my hunk header, but I get nothing. :(

## EDIT:

I've tried the solution proposed by torek, but to no avail.  It's like it doesn't know what to do with the `xfuncname` entry. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was due to my mixed environment.  As I am using git under cygwin and windows directly, I have two home directories that are being looked at.  The Cygwin and the Windows.  So, I created a link to my `.gitconfig` in my Cygwin home directory from my Windows one.  Unfortunately I forgot to also link my `.gitattributes` file.

It was because of this missing file, that it wouldn't use the proper diff `xfuncname`.

This issue has now been resolved by creating the appropriate link.

Answer (score 2):

Though the question was resolved as being due to a peculiar reason with the OP's setup, a possible reason for this problem that might afflict a larger set of users is that `git` does not look for a global `~/.gitattributes` home directory file at all. So if you happen put the definitions there, they are being ignored.

The `~/.gitattributes` file is not parallel to `~/.gitconfig`; it is not expected in the same places. This inconsistency can cause confusion.

Though `git` is finding my `~/.gitconfig` file, `strace` shows that it's looking for the attributes file in these places:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/gitattributes", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/kaz/.config/git/attributes", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".gitattributes", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/info/attributes", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "src/.gitattributes", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Only the first two of these places are outside of the current git repository: it's looking in `/etc` and in `$HOME/.config`, and that's it.

You must create a `~/.config/git/attributes` file not `~/.gitattributes`.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult for several reasons:

- regexps are notoriously difficult in the first place, and
- Git adds a layer of backslash interpretation.

Your regexp is pretty close.  Here's one that works for me:

```
[diff "natvis"]
        xfuncname = "^[ \\t]*<Type Name=\"([^\"]*)\".*$"
```

The main changes:

- remove some extra backslashes from the first part (they were not causing failure, but presumably you don't intend to allow literal backslashes as well as space-and-tab).
- add " Name=" in the middle -- this could be improved by allowing space-or-tab rather than just space, probably.

We can use POSIX `[[:space:]]` in place of `[ \\t]`, and the `.*$` at the end is redundant, so this can be converted to:

```
xfuncname = "^[[:space:]]*<Type[[:space:]][[:space:]]*Name=\"([^\"]*)\""
```

which is more verbose but avoids the tricky `\\t` encoding.

Comment: Thanks @torek, but I've tried similar and have tried you solution without success. :(  What version and on what platform is your git?

Comment: Git 2.11(ish, plus or minus a minor rev) on BSD/Linux/Mac. Tested on FreeBSD.

Comment: Perhaps this is localized to just windows then?  Can someone confirm this?