# xfuncname not working in my .gitconfig file?

Tags: git, diff, customization

I know that there is a question with same title: [Why isn't my xfuncname working in my .gitconfig file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42078376/12357035). But it didn't solve my problem.

This is my .attributes file:

```
*.drd diff=drd
```

This is my config file:

```
[diff "drd"]
    textconv = echo hi
    xfuncname = "^.*$"
```

This is the diff output:

```
diff --git a/pool/occ.drd b/pool/occ.drd
index e71f8f3..fd07e44 100644
--- a/pool/occ.drd
+++ b/pool/occ.drd
@@ -1 +1 @@
-hi /tmp/XkCI8G_occ.drd
+hi /tmp/TEt4oH_occ.drd
```

Git is correctly recognizing 'textconv' attribute. But it is failing to recognize 'xfuncname'. I'm not sure why. Can someone please help me.

Git version: git version 2.7.4

Comment: There is not function name to find *before* the diff hunk. Have more than 4 lines, and have at least 4 leading lines where there is no change, then a "function name" should be visible. Try `printf '%s\n' line1 line2 line3 line4` instead of `echo hi`.

Comment: @j6t, so if function name is included in the hunk, then it will not appear as hunk header. Is that right? Is it possible to change that?

Comment: You are right. No, that can't be changed.